Impact on CatBoost Performance When Converting Categories to Strings
I'm using CatBoost for a machine learning project and encountering an issue with categorical features that contain null values. When I train my model, I get the following error:
_catboost.CatBoostError: Invalid type for cat_feature[object_idx=0,feature_idx=8]=NaN: cat_features must be integer or string, real number values and NaN values should be converted to string.

To resolve this error, I convert the categorical columns from category type to string and fill null values with a placeholder:
cat_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=["object", "category"]).columns)
df[cat_cols] = df[cat_cols].astype(str)
df[cat_cols].fillna("__NA__", inplace=True)

This approach fixes the error, but I am concerned about the potential impacts on performance:

Does converting categorical data from type 'category' to 'string' affect the accuracy or efficiency of model training or prediction in CatBoost?
Are there any known risks or downsides to this method in terms of memory usage or processing speed?


Helo, As far as I remember you should explicitly state to catboost which columns are categorical. Check cat_features attribute when initializing your CatBoostClassifier classifier. Thus if you've stated that column is categorical it will be processed as categorical and not as string.
